# How can code libraries be used with a libgdx core project?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

With Android development in Eclipse, I can put my utility classes(Util.java etc) in a library project that I can reuse in several android projects.

Is something similar possible with libgdx/gradle ? I want to have some common utility classes that can be reused in multiple libgdx Core projects.

Later edit: I can probably compile a jar file and include it in all libgdx projects, but I want a solution without a jar, I want a separate project.

Comment: Yes. The process is the same as with any other Android project.

Comment: I think the question was not clear enough. I want "utility" project that I can access from the core subproject. Not just android, core subproject is used in all subprojects: android, web, desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only need .java files:

**Eclipse**

Create a directory on your computer for storing your shared code. Go to the Properties for your core libgdx project. Under Java Build Path, on the Source tab, click the Link Source... button. Under Select Folder Location, put your directory for the shared code. In the box for Folder Name, you put the name it will appear under in your project (a virtual directory name). You could call it something like `myLib-src`.

Repeat these steps for as many different projects as you like, using the same shared directory. You can now put .java files in that directory from within your core project, and they will show up in other projects that link that same source directory. You might have to clean or refresh projects as you switch between them.

**Intellj IDEA / Android Studio**

Open the `build.gradle` file in your core module. You should see a line like this:

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
```

Change it to

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/", "path/to/your/library/sourcecode"]
```

This can be a relative directory, so if it's in a folder that's a sibling to your project directory, you can put

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/", "../../myLib-src" ]
```

Repeat these steps for as many different projects as you like, using the same shared directory.

Comment: Interesting! However looking at "Properties" than "Java Build Path" I noticed that there is a "Projects" tab(not just a Source tab). There I can include my common util project. I will not use the folder solution but at least you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!